# How do I get the sheet's name using github.com/tealeg/xlsx?

Tags: excel, go

I am using [`github.com/tealeg/xlsx`](http://github.com/tealeg/xlsx) to read XLSX files.
It is read pretty fast, however I would like to read by Sheet Name.
Does anyone know how to do?

```
// by sheet index works fine

xlFile,err := xlsx.OpenFile(xlsFile)

for _,sheet := range xlFile.Sheets {

 for _,row := range sheet.Rows {

 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the map `Sheet` contained in [`xlsx.File`](http://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/xlsx#File) and access by key (the key is your sheet name):

```
xlFile, err := xlsx.OpenFile(xlsFile)
// check err

sheetName := "YourSheetName"
sheet := xlFile.Sheet[sheetName]
```